# Farewell, bullets in unordered list

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, mobile-web

Google Chrome 64.0.3282.137 (Google Play), Android 7.1.1

> [image: no bullets are shown for each list item]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A fix for this will go live in the next build out of Stack Overflow. We moved some things around in our CSS reset, and unordered lists for mobile seem to have gotten lost in the shuffle. Thanks for reporting this!

Comment: Hey, how can the red tag be suggested instead of applied directly?

Comment: hmm. are there any really good reasons for it? Feels like it belongs in a meta post ;p

Comment: Because he doesn't have a diamond, but just employee status.

Comment: @ɪʙᴜɢ there is special "employee" status for a user behind the scenes, which grants some moderator privileges,  but not all of them. The ability to add moderator tags is one of them, however editing is not. It's a mess, so if one need to do that on regular basis they usually get a diamond. (e.g. Joe Friend)